# Android Studio 2 error

Tags: android-studio, drag-and-drop

I have the latest Java version installed as you can see, but it still tells me the message. Moreover, I can not load any projects because it gets stuck in the gradle building process. Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine after reinstalling the JDK(500mb) pack, rather than the update (66mb).